# Neon Optimization for multiplication and store in ARM

Tags: gcc, arm, simd, intrinsics, neon

Using an ARM Cortex A15 board I'm trying to optimize a perfectly working C code by using NEON intrinsics.

compiler: gcc 4.7 on ubuntu 12.04

Flags:-g -O3  -mcpu=cortex-a15 -mfpu=neon-vfpv4 -ftree-vectorize -DDRA7XX_ARM -DARM_PROC -DSL -funroll-loops -ftree-loop-ivcanon -mfloat-abi=hard

I wanted to do the following function ,its just a simple load->multiply->store.

here are some parameters: 
   *input is a pointer to an array of size 40680 and after completing the loop the pointer should retain the current position and do the same for next input stream via input pointer.

```
            float32_t A=0.7;
            float32_t *ptr_op=(float*)output[9216];
            float32x2_t reg1;

             for(i= 0;i< 4608;i+=4){        
                /*output[(2*i)] = A*(*input); // C version
                input++;                 
                output[(2*i)+1] = A*(*input);
                input++;*/

                reg1=vld1q_f32(input++);    //Neon version              
                R_N=vmulq_n_f32(reg1,A);
                vst1q_f32(ptr_op++,R_N);
            }
```

I want to understand where am I making mistake in this loop because it seems pretty straightforward.

Here is my assembly implementation of the same . Am I going in the correct direction???

```
__asm__ __volatile__(
              "\t mov r4, #0\n"
              "\t vdup.32 d1,%3\n"
              "Lloop2:\n"
              "\t cmp r4, %2\n"
              "\t bge Lend2\n"
              "\t vld1.32  d0, [%0]!\n"             
              "\t vmul.f32 d0, d0, d1\n"
              "\t vst1.32 d0, [%1]!\n"
              "\t add r4, r4, #2\n"
              "\t b Lloop2\n"
              "Lend2:\n"
              : "=r"(input), "=r"(ptr_op), "=r"(length), "=r"(A)
              : "0"(input), "1"(ptr_op), "2"(length), "3"(A)
              : "cc", "r4", "d1", "d0");
```

Comment: What is the question? Is there an error to report?

Comment: You need to understand the comments from your last question. NEON done poorly (as you've done above) will not perform much better than scalar instructions. You need to make use of lots of registers to hide pipeline and memory latencies. If this doesn't make sense, then you need to learn about it before writing NEON code.

Comment: can you please explain where those problems are occurring in my loop??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hmmmmm, does your code compile in the first place? I didn't know that you can multiply a vector by a float scalar. Probably the compiler did convert if for you.

Anyway, you have to understand that most NEON instructions are bound with a long latency. Unless you hide them properly, your code won't be any faster than the standard C version, if not slower.

```
vld1q..... // 1 cycle
// 4 cycles latency + potential cache miss penalty
vmulq..... // 2 cycles
// 6 cycles latency
vst1q..... // 1 cycle
// 2 cycles loop overhead
```

The example above roughly shows the cycles required for each iteration.

And as you can see, it's minimum 18 cycles/iteration from which only 4 cycles are spent on actual computation while 14 cycles are wasted meaninglessly.

It's called `RAW dependency` (Read after Write)

The easiest and practically only way to hide these latencies is loop unrolling: a deep one.

Unrolling by four vectors per iteration is usually sufficient, and eight is even better, if you don't mind the code length.

```
void vecMul(float * pDst, float * pSrc, float coeff, int length)
{
    const float32x4_t scal = vmovq_n_f32(coeff);
    float32x4x4_t veca, vecb;

    length -= 32;

    if (length >= 0)
    {
        while (1)
        {
            do
            {
                length -= 32;
                veca = vld1q_f32_x4(pSrc++);
                vecb = vld1q_f32_x4(pSrc++);

                veca.val[0] = vmulq_f32(veca.val[0], scal);
                veca.val[1] = vmulq_f32(veca.val[1], scal);
                veca.val[2] = vmulq_f32(veca.val[2], scal);
                veca.val[3] = vmulq_f32(veca.val[3], scal);
                vecb.val[0] = vmulq_f32(vecb.val[0], scal);
                vecb.val[1] = vmulq_f32(vecb.val[1], scal);
                vecb.val[2] = vmulq_f32(vecb.val[2], scal);
                vecb.val[3] = vmulq_f32(vecb.val[3], scal);

                vst1q_f32_x4(pDst++, veca);
                vst1q_f32_x4(pDst++, vecb);
            } while (length >= 0);

            if (length <= -32) return;

            pSrc += length;
            pDst += length;
        }
    }

///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

    if (length & 16)
    {
        veca = vld1q_f32_x4(pSrc++);
    }

    if (length & 8)
    {
        vecb.val[0] = vld1q_f32(pSrc++);
        vecb.val[1] = vld1q_f32(pSrc++);
    }

    if (length & 4)
    {
        vecb.val[2] = vld1q_f32(pSrc++);
    }

    if (length & 2)
    {
        vld1q_lane_f32(pSrc++, vecb.val[3], 0);
        vld1q_lane_f32(pSrc++, vecb.val[3], 1);
    }

    if (length & 1)
    {
        vld1q_lane_f32(pSrc, vecb.val[3], 2);
    }

    veca.val[0] = vmulq_f32(veca.val[0], scal);
    veca.val[1] = vmulq_f32(veca.val[1], scal);
    veca.val[2] = vmulq_f32(veca.val[2], scal);
    veca.val[3] = vmulq_f32(veca.val[3], scal);
    vecb.val[0] = vmulq_f32(vecb.val[0], scal);
    vecb.val[1] = vmulq_f32(vecb.val[1], scal);
    vecb.val[2] = vmulq_f32(vecb.val[2], scal);
    vecb.val[3] = vmulq_f32(vecb.val[3], scal);

    if (length & 16)
    {
        vst1q_f32_x4(pDst++, veca);
    }

    if (length & 8)
    {
        vst1q_f32(pDst++, vecb.val[0]);
        vst1q_f32(pDst++, vecb.val[1]);
    }

    if (length & 4)
    {
        vst1q_f32(pDst++, vecb.val[2]);
    }

    if (length & 2)
    {
        vst1q_lane_f32(pDst++, vecb.val[3], 0);
        vst1q_lane_f32(pDst++, vecb.val[3], 1);

    }

    if (length & 1)
    {
        vst1q_lane_f32(pDst, vecb.val[3], 2);
    }
}
```

Now we are dealing with eight **independent** vectors, hence the latencies are completely hidden, and the potential cache miss penalty as well as the flat loop overhead are rather diminishing.

Comment: PS: If you are using an old compiler, it may not recognize `float32x4x4_t`. In that case, you have no choice but declare vec1~vec8 as `float32x4_t`, and map them accordingly. When it comes to NEON, writing assembly codes more than pays off IMO.

Comment: float32x2_tvmul_n_f32(float32x2_t a, float32_t b);                              this is from the arm reference guide ,so whatever code im trying to write is from there itself ,yes now i see very clearly how assembly in these cases is much better

Comment: `veca = vld1q_f32_x4(pSrc++)`   gcc doesnt support this one so i mapped it  `veca.val[0] to [3]` ,then it compiled but i guess my compiler ruined it again ,cycles increased drastically.

Comment: @Skynet NEON intrinsics got improved at GCC version 6.x. If you can, you should give it a try. What prevents you from using assembly?

Comment: I'm doing these as a part of my internship and gcc 4.7 is what I got and I'm not allowed to change it, can you please take a look at my inline assembly in the question and give your inputs .thank you.

Comment: @Skynet It doesn't prevent you from linking external static libs. You can build NEON functions separately to a static lib, then link it to your main project. That's the only solution. It's absolutely pointless programming in intrinsics on GCC 4.7

Comment: can you please  guide me how to do that i tried to read  a lot of posts but its all confusing                                                                    
 .gcc-linaro-arm-linux-gnueabihf-4.7-2013.03-20130313_linux  ,this is the compiler im currently using

Comment: @Skynet Download ARM DS5 community edition and the most recent gcc from linaro.org. And follow this guide https://developer.arm.com/products/software-development-tools/ds-5-development-studio/resources/tutorials/adding-new-compiler-toolchains-to-ds-5.

Comment: @Skynet Then start a new project(static library), compile the function above in release mode. You will get  a static library with the extension .a; Add it to your makefile. Then you will just have to write a function prototype to call it from your project.